# How can I use a tLogCatcher to catch messages from subjobs?

Tags: talend

I currently have a job with one main job orchestrating several sub-jobs.

Each job (main and sub-jobs) contain `tWarn` components to emit status messages and useful debug info.

I also have a `tLogCatcher` in each job sending messages to `sdtout`. Sending to `stdout` is easy enough, but now I want to send the messages to a logstash instance using HTTP as transport. This is becoming a bit unwieldy to put into each job.

Can I - and if yes "how?" - use a `tLogCatcher` to catch *all* messages. Not just the one from the job the component is located in! That way I could centralise the logstash logic.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't use just one `tLogCatcher` to catch all messages from subjobs.

Long answer: you can centralize the logging using many `tLogCatcher`. To centralize that logstash logic: create a subjob containing that logic and call that job from the `tLogCatcher` in each subjob. So instead of propagating the log-message up - you delegate down.